# Metadata version number in Journey Builder Custom Activities

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

The Custom Activities in the [custom-activity-deskapi-node](https://github.com/sfmc-developer-advocates/custom-activity-deskapi-node) example application include a `version` name/value pair in the `metaData` object in the config.json files:

```
{
    "workflowApiVersion": "1.0",
    "metaData": {
        "version": "2.0",
        "icon": "images/jb-icon.jpg",
        "iconSmall": "images/jb-icon.jpg"
    },
```

I can't find any documentation related to this version number. Can someone clarify:

1. Is this name/value pair required in a Custom Activity?
2. Is this version number a developer-assigned iterative version number for the Custom Activity? Or does it have a specific role within an Interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it to anything.  It's just the version number of your development iteration for that particular activity.  In the [custom activity example](https://github.com/sfmc-developer-advocates/custom-activity-deskapi-node) I pulled version from package.json to display in the configuration.  But it could instead be pulled from this metaData version.